# Single CANOE configuration to handle multiple(2) sub canoe configurations

Tags: integration, capl, canoe

I  want to have a single canoe configuration which will prompt user to select his/her choice of interest on CAN speed . I have two seperate canoe configurations developed ,one on high speed CAN(500Kbps) and another on CANFD(2000kbps).And each config has its own set of Nodes simulated .Now I don't want have a seperate configs instead want to have one cong which will load respective config's when user selects his/her CAN speed.

Can I integrate these two seperate config's into one so that if I select HS-CAN ,I need to have its simulated nodes being displayed in the simuation setup and if I select CANFD ,I need to have its simulated nodes being displayed in the simuation setup.

Comment: How is the user supposed to "select his/her CAN speed"?

Answer (score -1):

Well, depends hon how dirty you want to have it...

If you're not using VN89xx in standalone mode, there is no "standard" way to have a "master" configuration and then load other configs.

However, you can call CANoe from within CANoe, with SysExecCmd canoe32.exe /a /f "config" to launch CANoe und then immediatly exit canoe from within capl. That's dirty but should work (see CANoe and CAPL help for references). Oh, and don't forget to recall the master configuration after the other configuration finished. This has load times, though...

You can also manually integrate both simulations into the same configuration onto separate CAN buses. You then must assure, only one bus can run at the same time. If you have two piggies: fine. Wire them together externally and you're done. If you don't, each time you change bus (via a CAPL script, stopping and starting the respective simulation), the CAN parameters must be reset to the required specification. Then, in the hardware configuration, set both channels to the same transceiver and ignore the popup telling you, that this is a bad idea (works only with CAN).

Worst would be, of course, to implement everything onto the same bus in CANoe and handle it there.

Best case would be: Don't have such requirements or use external tools. Or usesrs that know what they're doing. CANoe is almost fully scriptable via ActiveX, if you want to go down *that* rabbit hole...

Sorry to say but this is generally one of the things you want to avoid. ;-)